# automate multiple file conversions

Tags: bash, scripts, conversion

I need help fixing my script to automate multiple file conversions.
I am working on the server and I am trying to find a way to convert files automatically.

The conversion needs to be made through four formats: sam, bwa, and bcf, and vcf
The files increment at two spots like this. Each increment has two file formats: .sai and .fastq

```
004_001
004_002
004_003
004_004
```

Then

```
005_001
005_002
005_003
005_004
```

I have tried:

Code:

```
for i in {1..4}
do 
    $bwa samse $hg19 $csai $cfas > *.sam
done
```

But it only worked with the `_001` file all four times.
I have tried setting the end increment to i so instead of `_001` it's `_00$((i))` to go 1,2,3,4 but its stays at 1.

Example of sam conversion:

```
for i in {1..4}
do 
./bwa samse  /hg19.fa  *_00$((i)).sai *_00$((i)).fastq  > *_00$((i)).sam
done
```

I wrote it to run input files with that name and output data to the sam file.  
It works but it converts `_001` four time instead of `_001` to `_004`

Basically I need to write a script that will automate multiple file conversions

- 3 file inputs > output 1 file .sam
- input .sam file > output .bam file
- input .bam file > output .bcf file
- input .bcf file > output .vcf file

Answer (score 3):

Well the syntax of the command can help you

```
bwa samse [-n max_occ] [-f out.sam] [-r RG_line] <prefix> <in.sai> <in.fq>
```

Now let's look at your bash:

```
for j in {004,005}; do
    for i in {001..004}; do
        bwa samse -f $j_$i.sam $hg19 $j_$i.sai $j_$i.fastq

        # Do the other conversions from $j_$i.sam
        samtools view -bS $j_$i.sam > $j_$i.bam
        samtools mpileup -uf genome.fa $j_$i.bam | bcftools view -bvcg - > $j_$i.bcf 
    done
done
```

**I have no idea what `$hg19` is.**
It expects a "prefix" there so if you know what that means, substitute it in.

Anyway, that should generate 8× .sam files. You can either change the loop above so that after generating the .sam with `bwa`, you perform your other conversions, like so:

```
for j in {004,005}; do
    for i in {001..004}; do
        bwa samse -f $j_$i.sam $hg19 $j_$i.sai $j_$i.fastq

        # Do the other conversions from $j_$i.sam
        samtools view -bS $j_$i.sam > $j_$i.bam
        samtools mpileup -uf genome.fa $j_$i.bam | bcftools view -bvcg - > $j_$i.bcf
        # ... whatever is needed to convert bcf to vcf  ...
    done
done
```

Or you can do a separate loop(s): `for f in *.sam; do command $f ...; done`.

Comment: $19 references hg19.fa file the full file for 004 or 005 is name is an organism example "dog_473y_K004_S3_00$((i)).sai"

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with the incrementing counter, you don't need it and it just complicates things. Try this instead:

```
for file in 0*.sai; do 
    bwa samse hg19.fa $file ${file%.sai}.fastq  > ${file%.sai}.sam
done
```

#### Explanation

- `for file in 0*.sai;` : iterate through all `0*.sai` files in the current directory.
- `${file%.sai}` : remove `.sai` from the end of `$file`. This means that if `file=001_001.sai`, `${file%.sai}.fastq` will be `001_001.fastq`.

This way, you will iterate through all files and run the conversion correctly without needing to fiddle with counters. I don't know what command you'd use to convert to the other formats since I've never worked with NGS data but you can add whatever is needed to the loop:

```
for file in 0*.sai; do 
    bwa samse hg19.fa $file ${file%.sai}.fastq  > ${file%.sai}.sam
    command2 $file ${file%.sai}.fastq  > ${file%.sai}.bwa, 
    command2 $file ${file%.sai}.fastq  > ${file%.sai}.bcf 
    command2 $file ${file%.sai}.fastq  > ${file%.sai}.vcf 
done
```

Comment: It makes sense, but files .sai and .fastq are different files that supposed to be input together like this "bwa samse hg19.fa .sai .fastq > .sam"

Comment: @user298390 I know, that's what my answer is doing. `$file` will be `001_001.sai` and `${file%.sai}.fastq` will be `001_001.fastq`. The actual command being run will be `bwa samse hg19.fa 001_001.sai 001_001.fastq > 001_001.sam` (where `001_001` changes with each iteration). This might explain better: `file=foo.sai; echo $file ${file%.sai}.fastq`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help guys. I have perfected my script to work on with multithreading. I appreciate all the help.